# How to calculate the change of the density of photons in different frames?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, field-theory

I have a problem in getting the transformation of the intensity of light.

1>> Using the transformation of the energy-momentum tensor $T^{ik}$, we can obtain

[image]

We have used the fact that $T^{00}=W$ is the energy density of the electromagnetic field. And the intensity of light is
$$\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{n}cW$$
So we can get the transformation of the intensity. This equation can be found in The Classical Theory of Fields by L. D. Landau.

2>> But we can regard light as a combination of photons. The frequency of photons can tranform like 4-vector $$(\frac{\omega}{c},\mathbf{k})$$
So we get

[image]

Then the intensity of light is equal to the number of photons timed by $\hbar\omega$.

So as we can see if we assume the number of photons doesn't change under the Lorentz transformation. we will get different answers. The first answer is the square of the second one. Why?

If we try to figure out the contraction of density, we can't just use the contraction factor $1/\gamma$, which is derived from the rest frame. How to solve it?

Comment: Light moves at velocity c  and your first term is 0/0. One cannot apply a lorentz transformation to photons also traveling at velocity c.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has wrong assumptions about light

Comment: @annav:  It's perfectly legitimate to apply a Lorentz transformation to any sort of stress-energy tensor, including those stress-energy tensors resulting from massless particles.  The velocity $V$ in the OP's equations is the velocity of another observer's frame.

Comment: @annav: Hi, I think the first question can be found in The Classical Theory of Field by L.D. Landau.

Comment: @annav Having wrong assumptions isn't really a good reason to close a question. If someone's assumptions are wrong, that can be part of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the second frame, the volume you are measuring is Lorentz-contracted compared to the first.  This means that the number density of the photons changes.  In other words, the change in the energy density between the two frames can be thought of as coming from two factors:  the blue-shifting of the individual photons, and a change in the number density of photons.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am wondering how to calculate the change in the number density of photons. The contraction along the x-axis only contributes to a factor, $1/\gamma$, which is still different from the same answer.

Comment: My bad. Maybe I can't get the factor, $1/\gamma$, which is derived from the rest frame of particles.